# How to show that $1 + 2\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(\frac{3x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not sure what to add beyond what's in the title. I've spent a while toying with trig identities from both sides, and I just can't figure out how to connect them. Plugging them into a graphing calculator shows that they are in fact equal (at least where they are both defined).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: $\sin(3x/2)=\sin(x+\tfrac{x}{2})$

Comment: @ Oliver, yes I've explored that as best as I could.

$\sin(x + \frac{1}{2}x) = \sin(x)\cos(\frac{1}{2}x) + \cos(x)\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)$

Then what? The right hand term becomes $\cos(x)$ after canceling the denominator. The left hand term becomes $2\cos^2(\frac{1}{2}x)$ after another transform and cancelling?

All that adds up to $\cos(x) + 2\cos^2(\frac{1}{2}x)$ ... then what?

Comment: then write $x=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}$ if what you are trying to prove is indeed true, it may show after another application of sin (cos) os sum of angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}= \dfrac{3\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-4\sin^3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}= 3-4\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=3 - 4\cdot \dfrac{1-\cos x}{2}= 3 - 2(1-\cos x)=1+2\cos x$.

Comment: Hmmm can you add a tip on how you spot $\sin(\frac{3x}{2}) = 3\sin(\frac{x}{2} - 4\sin^3(\frac{x}{2})$? That's doesn't look like anything I've seen before.

Comment: You may rewrite the $\sin(3u)$ for $u = \dfrac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Okay, I guess I have just never seen a formula for triple angle like that before, but I managed to work it out through complex exponentials just now, so I get the idea, thanks!